# How to calculate RGB+A+W (Amber + White) from RGB for LEDs

Tags: c#, math, rgb, led

I need to write a function that takes RGB (0-255) input and outputs 5 values to drive a RGBAW LED (integrated chip that has red, blue, green, amber and white individual LEDs in one module). The output from my function has to be 5x 0-255 values. My preferred language is C#, but I can probably convert from any language.

I basically have a RGB input (call it Ri, Gi, Bi) each at 0-255. The LEDs are assumed to be calibrated to the same light output. From the output I want to calculate what output I should have for each of the five LEDs (R, G, B, A, W).

I want to make sure the light output isn't washed out with white when for example doing 100% Red (Ri = 255).

The function should look something like this:

```
public void CalculateRGBAW(byte ri, byte gi, byte bi, out byte r, out byte g, out byte b, out byte a, out byte w)
{
    r = ri;
    g = gi;
    b = bi;
    a = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;
    w = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;
}
```

This is the type of LED light fixture this will drive: [MARQ Gamut PAR H7](http://www.marqlighting.com/products/view/gamutpar-h7), the user guide is linked there too (which doesn't say anything about how these are calibrated, this light fixture isn't high end so that's probably why, I think we just need to assume they are calibrated as far as this question is concerned).

Comment: Please let me know if the edits I've made has improved this question, and if not please let me know what I can provide to remove the down votes. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need to calibrate your **LED**s to obtain normalization coefficients

1. **R,G,B**

   if `R=G=B` the output color should be gray-scale shade. To achieve this use scale coefficients for example:

   ```
   R'=r*R
   G'=g*G
   B'=b*B
   ```

   where `r,g,b` are scale coefficients and `R,G,B` are your ideal input values. The `R',G',B'` are values send to your LED driver. This equation is assuming linear behavior if not the case you need to change equation for example to polynomial like:

   ```
   R'=r0 + r1*R + r2*R^2 + ...
   ```

   Now you send `R'=G'=B'=10` and check for the light color. If not white decrement the color which is exceeding white-ish. do this until you got white-ish color.

   Do this for more starting values like `R'=G'=B'=10 , R'=G'=B'=20 , R'=G'=B'=30 , ...` and remember the values after tuning to white. For example

   ```
    R` G` B`   beg
   10 10 12    10
   20 20 24    20
   30 30 36    30
   ```

   so in this example the blue **LED** is not as shiny as the `R,G` so it need to be scaled. From these few points you can estimate the dependence is linear without offset so

   ```
   r=1
   g=1
   b=36/30=24/20=12/10=1.2
   ```

   You need integers so you can use fixed point arithmetics like

   ```
   b=(12*256)/10 = 307
   B'=(B*b)/256
   ```
2. **White**

   You need balance white to white. Ideally you should find `R,G,B` values that match a `W` value. and create functions

   ```
   Rw(W),Gw(W),Bw(W)
   ```

   which will match `W` with `RGB` **LED**s. that will not be easy and may be some webcam with pixel picking tool will help (but must be also balanced).
3. **Amber**

   similarly you need to find

   ```
   Ra(A),Ga(A),Ba(A)
   ```

   which will match `A` with `RGB` LEDs. as in the **#2**

**color mixing**

After calibration you should have `R,G,B,A,W` values linearized so you can use arithmetics on them. So to enhance your dynamic range let assume `Ri,Gi,Bi` are your input color values you want to drive. Here are some dependencies for the **LED**s

```
         R   G   B
White = (W/3,W/3,W/3)
Amber = (A  ,A/2,0  )
```

So White can ease up all of the `R,G,B`

```
W = min(Ri,Gi,Bi)/3
R = Ri-W
G = Gi-W
B = Bi-W
```

Amber can ease up `R,G` so find `A`

```
A = R
if (A>G*2) A=G*2
R = Ri-A
G = Gi-A/2
B = Bi
```

And when put all together

```
W = min(Ri,Gi,Bi)/3
A = Ri-W
if (A>(Gi-W)*2) A=(Gi-W)*2
R = Ri-W-A
G = Gi-W-A/2
B = Bi-W
```

So now you can use `Ri,Gi,Bi` even above `<0-255>` (for some colors) and still have `R,G,B` in `<0,255>`. You can also use `W` as brightness and `A` as yellow balance (warmth)

Comment: One question, if I have 100% Red (Ri) for example, that means the above formula will add in 33% white, which will make the output more pink. Is there a an alternative so the white doesn't wash out the colors?

Comment: @Haukman if you got 100% red that means 0% Green and 0% Blue so min(255,0,0) is 0 so no white and no pink at all

Comment: Oh, my bad, I missed the "min" part, I see it now, thank you!

Comment: One more question here, I tested this out and with the /3 on the white component the white seems to not be bright enough, I removed it and it seems to work better, do you think that's a better way? Other than that it works really good!

Comment: @Haukman well that depends on the scale of the LEDs ... the driver you are using most likely divide by 3 on its own ... If you did do the calibration then the equations will stay as are and you would just found the scale coefficients for white to be different then R,G,B... by factor 3

Comment: Maybe, but at max 100% on all RGB I would only get 33% of the max potential output (white). I realize it's hard to know the scale between the RGB LEDs all turned on vs the white LED chip, but I don't want to miss out on full-scale white.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test, so this is just a guess, off of my head:

```
w = min (r, g, b)
a = min(r - w, g - w)  
r = r - w - a 
g = g - w - a  
b = b - w
```

Looks a bit bright, though, maybe `w = w / 3` and also `a = a / 2`..? You will surely need to tune for the actual LED colors.

Comment: not sure what for the downvote is but isnt amber `R=2G, B=0` ? you got `R=G, B=0` instead. I could be wrong I just google amber color image and use color pick tool ... (not good with English color names outside the ZX spectrum palette :))

Comment: Amber is a yellow-orange color. Color.Gold is closest among the named colors. So, yes, a little correction will be necessary; but the real numbers must be found looking at the actual LEDs.

Comment: A lot of the commercial light fixtures have these RGBAW chips, I'm sure they can be calibrated (and may need it), but I'd like to see if there is a generic function I can implement that will be mathematically correct for an ideal LED chip at least.